# D3 white tick marks (grid lines) are drawing over text, how to correct?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing a simple horizontal bar graph in D3.
I'm breaking the bars into smaller rectangles with long, white tick marks.
But my tick marks are slicing through some text.
I suspect I am drawing elements in the wrong order, somehow.
What do you think?
How to make gridlines slice only the bars, not the text?

You can see how it looks tacky, whole thing is here:
http://bl.ocks.org/greencracker/4378b817d4d5393c4e37

Here's the key part, I think:
...

```
  var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar") // create the bars
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.name) + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect") // draw the bars
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
      .style("opacity", 0.5);

  svg.append("g") // draw my x axis, which includes the white tickmarks
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis);

  bar.append("text") // then attach text to each bar
      .attr("class", "value")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor",  function (d) {
        if (d.name === "Business, Management, Marketing") {return "end"}
        else {return "start"} ;}) // correct for "business" being very long
      .attr("dx",  function (d) {
        if (d.name === "Business, Management, Marketing") {return -3}
        else {return 3} ;}) // correct for "business" being very long
      .text(function(d) { return (d.name); });
```

(Yes, I asked a similar question before, but this one's a little different and I can't figure it out. [Transition on axis -- losing grid lines (ticksize), how to transition in correct order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879115/transition-on-axis-losing-grid-lines-ticksize-how-to-transition-in-correct))

Comment: The thing is your code isn't slicing the text -- it just looks like it because the text is on top. I'm not sure what you would want to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your suspicions about drawing elements in the proper order are correct.

What's currently happening is:

1) Append <g class="bar"> for new data.

```
var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
```

2) Append a rectangle to the above group.

```
bar.append("rect")
```

3) Draw the x-axis, which is placed after (i.e. over) of (1).

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);
```

4) Append/nest text to the group defined in (1).

```
bar.append("text")
```

Since the text is nested with the group and the group is inserted into the DOM before the x-axis, the tickmarks are showing up over the text.

**However** if we do something as simple as say moving the x-axis call before the bar call, the ticks won't show up because they'll be drawn underneath the bars. So unfortunately you'll need to split up the grouping of rectangle and text.

This also means you'll need define a transform/translate for the text labels:

```
svg.selectAll("text.value")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "value")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate("+ x(d.value)+5 + "," + (12+y(d.name)) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor",  function (d) {
    if (d.name === "Business, Management, Marketing") {return "end"}
    else {return "start"} ;}) // correct for "business" being very long
  .attr("dx",  function (d) {
    if (d.name === "Business, Management, Marketing") {return -3}
    else {return 3} ;}) // correct for "business" being very long
  .text(function(d) { return (d.name); });
```

The above should work for all labels except for Business, Management, Marketing, because its translate is at 5800.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah. This was the key part.  I didn't realize the difference b/w "group" and "element." "Since the text is nested with the group and the group is inserted into the DOM before the x-axis, the tickmarks are showing up over the text."